# DbContext trying to save non-null fields as null

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have two projects

```
StoreSku.Data - Depends On: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
StoreSku.Provider - Depends On: StoreSku.Data, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

I don't want to tie `StoreSku.Data` to any particular provider, so I've moved that reposonsibility to `StoreSku.Provider`. I'm creating the model and options within `StoreSku.Provider` and passing the options into the `DbContext` using the following code:

```
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

var conventions = new ConventionSet();
var modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder(conventions);

modelBuilder.Entity<StoreSkuUpdateRequest>().HasKey(request => request.Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<StoreSkuUpdateRequest>().Property(request => request.Id).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();
modelBuilder.Entity<StoreSkuUpdateRequest>().Property(request => request.StoreNumber).ValueGeneratedNever();
modelBuilder.Entity<StoreSkuUpdateRequest>().Property(request => request.BusinessDate).ValueGeneratedNever();
modelBuilder.Entity<StoreSkuUpdateRequest>().Property(request => request.Timestamp).ValueGeneratedNever();
modelBuilder.Entity<StoreSkuUpdateRequest>().HasMany(request => request.RequestedUpdates).WithOne(update => update.UpdateRequest);
modelBuilder.Entity<StoreSkuUpdateRequest>().HasMany(request => request.RelatedUpdates).WithOne(relatedUpdate => relatedUpdate.UpdateRequest);
modelBuilder.Entity<StoreSkuUpdateRequest>().ForSqlServerToTable("StoreSkuUpdateRequest");

modelBuilder.Entity<StoreSkuAvailabilityUpdate>().HasOne(update => update.UpdateRequest).WithMany(request => request.RequestedUpdates);
modelBuilder.Entity<StoreSkuAvailabilityUpdate>().HasMany(update => update.RelatedUpdates).WithOne(relatedUpdate => relatedUpdate.RequestedUpdate);
modelBuilder.Entity<StoreSkuAvailabilityUpdate>().ForSqlServerToTable("RequestedStoreSkuUpdate");

modelBuilder.Entity<RelatedStoreSkuUpdate>().HasOne(relatedUpdate => relatedUpdate.RequestedUpdate).WithMany(update => update.RelatedUpdates);
modelBuilder.Entity<RelatedStoreSkuUpdate>().HasOne(relatedUpdate => relatedUpdate.UpdateRequest).WithMany(request => request.RelatedUpdates);
modelBuilder.Entity<RelatedStoreSkuUpdate>().ForSqlServerToTable("RelatedStoreSkuUpdate");

optionsBuilder.UseModel(modelBuilder.Model);

DbContextOptions options = optionsBuilder.Options;
```

As you can see, it's pretty verbose. Whether I need all of these calls is a different question. My question focuses more along these lines:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<StoreSkuUpdateRequest>().Property(request => request.StoreNumber).ValueGeneratedNever();
modelBuilder.Entity<StoreSkuUpdateRequest>().Property(request => request.BusinessDate).ValueGeneratedNever();
modelBuilder.Entity<StoreSkuUpdateRequest>().Property(request => request.Timestamp).ValueGeneratedNever();
```

The error that I've run into is that if I don't have these lines, I get the following errors:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'StoreNumber', table 'dbo.StoreSkuUpdateRequest'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'BusinessDate', table 'dbo.StoreSkuUpdateRequest'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Timestamp', table 'dbo.StoreSkuUpdateRequest'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
```

The schema for this table is

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StoreSkuUpdateRequest](
[Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[StoreNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
[BusinessDate] [date] NOT NULL,
[Timestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL)
```

And the model

```
public sealed class StoreSkuUpdateRequest
{
    [Required]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int StoreNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime BusinessDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

And the calling code:

```
using (Context)
{
    var request = new StoreSkuUpdateRequest
    {
        StoreNumber = 12345,
        BusinessDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
        Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow
    };
    Context.StoreSkuAvailabilityUpdateRequests.Add(request);

    Context.SaveChanges();
}
```

And the SQL command being generated is

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [StoreSkuUpdateRequest]
DEFAULT VALUES;
SELECT [Id]
FROM [StoreSkuUpdateRequest]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [Id] = scope_identity();

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

Why do I have to specify `ValueGeneratedNever();` for each of these properties? Why is EFCore trying to save them as `null`?

Comment: What is the relationship between the StoreSkuUpdateRequest and StoreSkuAvailabilityUpdate? I'm a bit confused in that you are creating an UpdateRequest but then adding it to AvailabilityUpdateRequests? There appears to be a relationship between the two (historical) but if this boils down to a FK relationship that EF has to resolve it may be doing something like an Insert+Update scenario. Check with an SQL profiler to see exactly what's being sent to the DB on SaveChanges.

Comment: The core cause of your issue is the `ModelBuilder` creation with **empty** `ConventionSet`, while the `ModelBuilder` passed to the normal `OnModelCreating` is initialized with a `ConventionSet` containing all EF Core conventions.

Comment: @IvanStoev I thought that might be a case, but I couldn't find any sort of `AllConventionsSet`, and all of the implementations are documented as `This API supports the Entity Framework Core infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases. `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment from Ivan Stoev in the original post, I stumbled upon this little bit from https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3529

> Discussed in triage and decided we should have ModelBuilder factories so that folks don't need to worry about conventions etc. (especially since conventions are 'internal' for the first release).
>
> Folks can just create one up like this (note this is a static Create() method on the factory rather than a default ctor to get a factory since having a default ctor doesn't play well with DI):
>
> `var builder = SqlServerModelBuilderFactory.Create()`
>
> Alternatively, if you want it to get all it's services from DI then we'll register one that you can just resolve... then you will get the same logger, etc. that is registered in DI (plus if you have overridden the type mapper etc. then you will also get those services).
>
> `sp.AddEntityFramework()
>     .AddSqlCompact()
>     .AddNpgSql()
>     .AddSqlServer()`;
>
> `var builder = sp.GetService<ISqlServerModelBuilderFactory>().Create();`

I wasn't able to find a `SqlServerModelBuilderFactory` class, which led me to investigate if there was a `SqlServerConventionSetBuilder`; there was.

So changing it from

```
var conventions = new ConventionSet();
```

to

```
var conventions = SqlServerConventionSetBuilder.Build();
```

Fixed me right up.